# How can I create a Satellite style map with Plotly and Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

Plotly provides an example of how to create a map with scattered points here:

https://plot.ly/pandas/scatter-plots-on-maps/

This example uses an Atlas style. There is a link to edit the chart on the example page which will open Plotly's user interface. Here I'm able to select "Satellite Map" which will create the same map, but with more detail. Does anyone know if there is a way to specify the map type as "Satellite" in the code itself?

I searched the reference documentation (https://plot.ly/python/reference) but could not find information about that setting.

Comment: I looks like `mapbox`, https://plot.ly/python/scattermapbox/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open [North American Precipitation Map](https://plot.ly/pandas/scatter-plots-on-maps/) in edit mode, you will see following map:

[image]

After that select satellite map instead of Atlas map.

Left side Menu:  **Style -> Layout -> Map style**
Then you can select options like outdoors,light,dark,satellite or satellite with streets. In following map outdoors style is selected. Hope this helps!

[image]

Please visit my github repository: https://github.com/SayaliSonawane/Plotly_Offline_Python/tree/master/Satellite%20Map

I have added one tutorial which explains how to create this type of plot in Python.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that out already. I was interested in being able to create a satellite map with code, not the interactive interface.

Comment: @sparrow Check edited answer. I have added link to my github repo about to how to create these types of plots in python.

Comment: Beautiful maps! Thank you so much!

Comment: do you know how to apply legendgroups to the type of maps in your example?